# Is there any way to specify Prefixes in AWS Athena S3 paths?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am trying to use Amazon Athena over S3 bucket which has two kinds of files.

a.file.txt
b.file.txt

I just want athena to target a.file.txt. Is it possible to specify it in console while creation of table?

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Creating tables for single files is not supported by Athena. You can only create a table on a directory level.

What is possible on the other hand is, creating a table on the directory level and filter the input file while querying.

You can filter the input file with the `$path` pseudo column.

```
select * from tablename
where "$path" = 's3://bucketname/directory/a.file.txt'
```